# How could *data inter-dependent* <select> dropdowns in rails be populated quickly?

Tags: html, ajax, performance, drop-down-menu, dependencies

Users need to select a car.
We have several dropdowns when picking a car in order to pick the year, make, model and submodel.
Initially we don't know what to use for the select options for make/model/submodel as they are interdependent.
Once we pick year we use ajax to make requests which query ActiveRecord to populate the make dropdown.
Then when we pick make we use ajax to query and populate the model dropdown.
Then when we pick model we ajax to query and populate the submodel dropdown.

The problem is that this is a lot of separate network requests and in real-world conditions of low bandwidth, network issues, etc. quite often there are pauses severely impacting the user experience and occasionally leading to failures.

What approaches could help avoid all these network requests.  In there an approach would could store all of the several thousand makes-model combinations on the client browser?

Currently the data is stored in a sql database accessed via ActiveRecord in the Rails framework.  Each dropdown selection results in another query because yuou can't show populate and show make until you know year and you can't populate and show model until you know make.  Same for submodel (though I've omitted submodel from the rest of this post for simplicity!).

Would session (http://simonsmith.io/speeding-things-up-with-sessionstorage/) storage of the JSON data for 10,000 combinations be possible?  I see that sessionStorage can generally be relied on to have at least 5MB(5,200,000 bytes) so that gives me 5200000/10000= 520 bytes per record.  Probably enough?  If this persists for the session and across pages then in many cases we could actually kick this off on the previous page and if that had time to finish we wouldn't need the external call at all on the relevant (next) page.
We would need to refresh that data either occasionally or on demand as new year-make-models are added periodically (several times a year).

Ultimately I think the solution here could be very useful to a large number of applications and companies.  The example here of picking a vehicle itself it used by dozens of major car insurance websites (who all do the multiple calls right now).  The general appraoch of storing client side data for relatioship dependent sdropdown could also mapply in many other situations such as online shopping for make-brand-year-model.  The backend framework to populate sessionStorage could also be done via different backend frameworks.

Another options might be to try google's Lovefield - https://github.com/google/lovefield  More at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1AUIq8GA1k
It's open source and works in ff, chrome, IE, Safari, etc.

Seems like sessionStorage might be better for our (considerable) business than basing it on a google 100 day dev thing - though it is open source.

Comment: What language is used for the backend (e.g.: c# .NET, php, jsp)? Or is this pure HTML and javascript?

Comment: You would be trading a small improvement in UI reaction time for loading a sh*t-load of data in the beginning already (which would likely cause a noticeable delay on application start), and most of that data will likely not even be used … I think this is a bad idea. Instead, I’d rather use some form of indicator that tells the user that new data is fetched based on their interaction with the UI.

Comment: Plus one @CBroe, yes that is true when working in our office with nice high-speed direct wire connection and so it wouldn't be worth it.  However out in the real world with low bandwidth wireless data connections (such as I frequently experience when not home) the delays play havoc on our (and others) UI's.  fields get skipped, workflow gets broken. UI tests fail intermittently.  It's a real problem.

Comment: Mobile data connections are often not only low-bandwidth, but also often have restrictions on data volumes – and I fear your are trading a little bit of convenience here for excessive amounts of data to download. When you say users will select “year, make, model and submodel”, that sounds like they will be looking for data pertaining to a very specific car, or at most a few – and loading the data for _all_ possible combinations up-front therefor sounds just incredibly bad from an economic point of view.

Comment: Having to pay for (extra) data volume is as much “real world” in many cases, as the speed issues you are citing. And as a user, I think I’d be rather pissed if you were wasteful with that resource, which I have to pay for.

Comment: And even for recurring users, that were to use your app quite often to look for data on different models – any possible caching on application level also uses a rather scarce resource, local storage space, that you have to compete for with the other apps the user has on their mobile device, and the rest of the data they want to keep on it (music/movies/pictures/…)

Comment: I am not saying you should not do it at all – but take into consideration all those other factors as well, to find what is the most reasonable compromise.

Comment: Great points!  Yeah I was thinking that in reality I should be under 10 or 20 per cent. of the available, if not less.  1-2% would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can create the JSON object 
for all the detail and based on the Value selected you can loop the array and populate the value. Let me

```js
var cardetail = [{
  "name": "MARUTI",
  "model": [{
    "name": "SWIFT",
    "year": ["2005", "2006", "2008"]
  }, {
    "name": "ALTO",
    "year": ["2009", "2010", "2011"]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Hundai",
  "model": [{
    "name": "I20",
    "year": ["2011", "2012", "2013"]
  }, {
    "name": "I20",
    "year": ["2013", "2014", "2015"]
  }]
}];

var currentCumpany = null;
var currentModel = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#company").append("<option value=''>Select Company</option>");
  for (i = 0; i < cardetail.length; i++) {
    $("#company").append("<option value='" + cardetail[i].name + "'>" + cardetail[i].name + "</option>");
  };

  $("#company").change(function() {

    for (i = 0; i < cardetail.length; i++) {
      if (cardetail[i].name == $("#company").val()) {
        currentCumpany = cardetail[i];
      }
    };
     $("#model").html("");
    for (i = 0; i < currentCumpany.model.length; i++) {
      $("#model").append("<option value='" + currentCumpany.model[i].name + "'>" + currentCumpany.model[i].name + "</option>");
    };
  });
   $("#company").change(function() {

    for (i = 0; i < cardetail.length; i++) {
      if (cardetail[i].name == $("#company").val()) {
        currentCumpany = cardetail[i];
      }
    };
     $("#model").html("");
    for (i = 0; i < currentCumpany.model.length; i++) {
      $("#model").append("<option value='" + currentCumpany.model[i].name + "'>" + currentCumpany.model[i].name + "</option>");
    };
  });
  

   $("#model").change(function() {

    
     
    for (i = 0; i < currentCumpany.model.length; i++) {
      
      if (currentCumpany.model[i].name == $("#model").val()) {
        currentModel = currentCumpany.model[i];
      }
      
    };
     
     
     $("#year").html("");
     
    for (i = 0; i < currentModel.year.length; i++) {
      $("#year").append("<option value='" + currentModel.year[i] + "'>" + currentModel.year[i] + "</option>");
    };
  });
  
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="company"></select>
<select id="model"></select>
<select id="year"></select>
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants as he clearly states: `Initially we don't know what to use for the select options for make/model/submodel as they are interdependent.` in your example it's not possible to select the year w/o selecting a company first.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is certainly part of the answer and a route I anticipated - use json to store the data locally.  Other parts of the answer are about getting this data.  Let me update the question a little more also.

Comment: Ok sure. initially default you want to show all the years and model?

Comment: Ok so your process will be like Select Year => Then Select Model => Select Sub model right?

Comment: What I understood was that he wants every possible increment. If the user selects year first then the other boxes should be filtered based on that year, but the user should also be able to select a make first which would filter the other boxes based on his selection.

Comment: Ok so it will be not clear old data right? Like in current Example there Select Swift then Select Hundai So the Model will show all four cars am i right?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant please check the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/35wdaq87/6/ Let me know it will work for you.

Comment: Yes that looks good.  However I'd like the lower level selectors to be cleared out when higher level ones are changed to values which don't exist, e.g. if you switch year and that make doesn't exist, clear it. Same for make and model for both changing year and changing make.  So this suggestion implies loading all the data up front I assume.  Will browsers be able to handle 10,000 combinations of jason for the year-make-model-submodel combinations of data that we have?

Comment: @Oceans, I only need the selection to be one-way.  Once you've selected year you are locked into that years makes and once you've selected make you're tied into that year-make's models.  To see different years for a given make you have to go thru year first.  This makes things a bit simpler.  A tricky part is determining when to gert and when to reset lower level selectors depending on whether the same combo exists for different years, makes, etc.

Comment: @Mitul Thanks!  Please also see my notes/thoughts about sessionStorage.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant here is the updated script **http://jsfiddle.net/35wdaq87/7/** And i have gone sessionStorage storage comment i will suggest to go with the **google's Lovefield** Its provide large data storage capability. Selecting query. Query filtering and all so that will be good. If i have time to do then i love to implement that.

Comment: That would be awesome to see!  I can throw you some extra points for that!

Comment: Ya sure. if you want to give, :)

Comment: Also, as posted to Jared, whichever solution one would use, minimizing network traffic would be a key component as one of the requirements is better functionality in a low bandwidth environment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92043/discussion-between-mitul-and-michael-durrant).

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First, unless the requisite bandwidth is too expensive you could conceivably check the cache and then start making requests for popular makes/models/submodels as soon as (or even before) the user picks a year and cache it. There's even a full [RDBMS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1AUIq8GA1k) for the browser now (full disclosure: its new and I haven't played with it much) which sits atop indexDB.

In terms of picking which ones to preload, you could do it based on units produced, units sold, car and driver magazine rankings, data-mining your actual users' requests, whatever.

I'm of the opinion that from a UX perspective you should at least be caching the requests the user actually makes and offering an option on load to jump right back to the last year/make/model they searched for rather than having them enter it all fresh each visit. Having popular vehicles preloaded only makes things easier. How much you want to push the envelope with predictive analysis of what a given user is likely to search for is up to your team skills/budget/time constraints.

I realize that this isn't a full answer per se, I'm not sure as stated the question has one (e.g. 'use *this* strategy/framework/library and all your problems will magically disappear! it even makes julienned fries!'). But if faced with this kind of problem my first thought is how to get more (hopefully relevant) data to the client *sooner*, which hopefully translates to *faster* (in the UX sense of fast).

I would also recommend that you have that popular data in json files to request rather than have to hit Rails/ActiveRecord/Database server each time. That alone would shave valuable milliseconds off your response times (not to mention usage load on those machines).

Its not like that data really changes, a 2009 Toyota Rav 4 has the same specs it did in...2009.

Comment: Maybe use session storage on the browser (http://simonsmith.io/speeding-things-up-with-sessionstorage/) for all the JSON ?

Comment: Depends on how long you want the data to persist. You could use `localStorage` if you want it to last longer than the current session. If you really want to cache loads of data on the client you can go all the way to `indexDB`. Problem w/`indexDB` is getting the data back out: it doesn't support as much SQL as one would hope (hence the library I linked to above). Just remember that there are limits that vary by browser: ~5MB for local/sessionStorage, ~50MB for indexDB.

Comment: I was hoping to use the initial load of both another ("landing") page and/or the initial load of this page.  It usually takes new users a few seconds to see the dropdown and start progressing through them. Say 2-5 seconds on each page.  It would be great to use that time to populate the year-make-model data.  Year is a fixed  list of year and while the user is seeing the page and finding and selecting that selector, the json data load could proceeding in the background is my thought.

Comment: Whichever solution one would use, minimizing network traffic would be a key component as one of the requirements is better functionality in a low bandwidth environment

Comment: I wouldn't embed the JSON (at least not all of it) in the initial page load then because then you don't know if you already have it in the cache or not (you'll end up burning bandwidth to re-download stuff you could have cached). I would set up whatever assets you need for an initial render and have the first js that executes start fetching JSON. You could also use a mixed strategy where you embed some of the JSON in the initial page and AJAX in the rest.